# What Kind of Medical Uses can the Force Help With?

Tags: star-wars

This came out of a few comments in chat regarding the midichlorians and Anakin's birth without a Father.  The first question was, "Can the Force be used as a contraceptive?"  Or that's what hit my mind originally.

But birth control, at least in humans, implies using the Force to manipulate bodily functions, which leads to an even bigger question: Is it possible to use the Force for medical use?  For instance, at a simple level, can it be used to apply pressure or stop bleeding?  And at a more complex level, can it speed up healing in any way?  (And, while we're at it, can it be used for birth control?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. in EU there are many examples of a [Healing Meditation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Healing_meditation) that Jedi use. Mostly on themselves, but Luke Skywalker was able to use it on others. This could be used to speed up healing of the wound or even mend broken bones (e.g. by Ki-Adi-Mundi).

Another example was Darth Vader whose body was gravely damaged but who managed to help it function using the Dark Side of the Force, including pain suppression (source: one of Bounty Hunters books IIRC). The Wikia summarizes this as:

> Darth Vader also experimented with Force healing fueled by the dark side, in which meditation on anger and frustration at his life and circumstances allowed his lungs to function without the aid of his hyperbaric chamber or his life support suit

There were also [Jedi Healers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_healer) (some mentioned in connection to Luke's Jedi Academy, some in Clone Wars settings - including a whole book, *[MedStar II: Jedi Healer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/MedStar_II%3a_Jedi_Healer)*).

The Healers used "[Jedi Healing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_healing)" powers - the examples are well documented in linked Wikia and numerous, so I won't list them here.

The most extreme example was [Dark Transfer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Transfer), used by Cade Skywalker, which allowed the user to bring others back to life from the brink of death. Originally thought to only be usable with Dark Side, it was later shown not to be the case.